# Is there any alternative way form avoiding $timeout in Angular 1

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am broadcasting an event from my parent controller and catching in child controller. So while executing listening function in child controller my UI renders and the changes which i have done is not reflecting on the page. When I add a $timeout of 100/200 ms it is working as expected. I need to invoke the function after the rendering of UI. Is there any way to do this apart from $timeout method?

```
$scope.$broadcast('update-field'); // in Parent Controller

//child controller
$scope.$on('update-field', () => { 
   $timeout(function() {
      $scope.exectuteUpdate();
   },200);
});
```

I need to call exectuteUpdate() after rendering of UI.

Comment: Did you try to add [$scope.$apply()](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html)?

Comment: Absolutely no. will check it out

Comment: This is a design flaw. The parent controller has to run before the child controller so sending an event immediately for child to receive makes no sense. This issue has nothing to do with `$apply` and more to do with sending event before listener exists

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$scope.$applyAsync`

```
$scope.$on('update-field', () => { 
   $scope.$applyAsync(() => {
   $scope.exectuteUpdate();
   });
});
```